# What are these potted trees with leafy branches beginning a few feet up a narrow trunk?

Tags: identification, trees

I saw these trees on Google Street view, and I really want to know what they are. They are located outside the back entrance to the Palace Hotel in San Francisco, California.

I may be able to physically visit if more detailed pictures help in identifying the trees.

[image: Hotel Tree 1]

[image]

[image: leaves]
[image: leaves2]
[image: bark]

Comment: need to see a close up of the leaves

Comment: @kevinsky- I agree that close up pictures are needed for identification. But, "quiet", have you considered calling the hotel and just asking? I don't know when you will be able to physically take more pictures, or if those pots will still be on the sidewalk, when you do. I called their listed number, and you can be connected to a live operator. I chose not to do so, but I don't see why you shouldn't pursue it, yourself. The landscaper may be honored that you were wondering

Comment: Hi Diane! Thank you for reaching out. That is indeed a good idea, and I've already done so. I got in touch with the building manager for the hotel, but they haven't been able to track down the type of plant yet. I will follow up with them as well in a few days. If they get back to me, I will be sure to post their response!

Comment: Sweet! I would love to see the answer!

Comment: This looks to me like olive trees. But won't be sure until close-up pictures.

Comment: @kevinsky I have added pictures of the leaves. Let me know if any other information might be helpful. Thank you! (Hotel still has yet to get back)

Comment: Hi quiet! I like these trees and your efforts to identify them! There a plenty of tree experts here, of which I'm definitely not one! I'm just curious though, do the leafy branches only start above the junctions of the trunk, or are there branches that have been cut off lower down? I ask this because, with your permission, I'm thinking of taking "bushy" out of the title and adding some other types of details that passers-by might see. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sue: That's a good idea. There are no branches under the trunk junctions, so bushy is not technically correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @quiet- I'm kind of new to the site, also. I have noticed that if you (as the poster) don't put the @ and the person's id in front of your responses, they don't show up in our inbox messages. (For instance, your responses to Sue and me wouldn't show up, even though you can see every response, without us tagging you.) Not 100% sure if that is how it works, but it seems to be. I had to search out your question again to see if you had any luck yet.

Comment: quiet- I went to to google street view and was able to zoom in on the tree that you took the close ups of. In that view, the trees appear to have fruit or nuts up top. Did you see any of these when you went there?https://www.instantstreetview.com/@37.787596,-122.402262,56.09h,-4.32p,2z

Comment: Here it is larger, with the nuts/fruit. https://www.instantstreetview.com/@37.787596,-122.402262,52.99h,4.64p,2z

Comment: @Shule- At first I thought that you might be right. But, here are Magnolia seed pods. They look very different than the ones in the enlarged street view in the link above. http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/magnolia-seeds-400x266.jpg

Comment: @Diane, right you are about the @ before names! Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't gotten that note. It's a bit confusing, but the description is on the SE Meta site, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work... It's also called "pinging" so if you see that word, it means to get in touch with someone using the @. It also works in chat. Sorry quiet, I didn't get your note. Let me see if I can do anything that will help you!

Comment: @Sue- Thanks for the explanation! I will check out the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hotel has responded. The tree is the New Zealand Christmas Tree, scientific name *Metrosideros Excelsa*.

Apparently, the tree was popular in 1980s San Francisco, but residents have since discovered that its roots are particularly problematic because they destroy underground infrastructure lines. - [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/08/27/us/27bcjames.html)

Comment: Wow, these trees are everywhere cause people like the red flowers at Xmas time. They're native to the south island of new Zealand, and we call them pōhutukawa trees, from the Maori name. People who are more "correct" would prefer we plant trees native to the north island in the North island.

Comment: Glad you found the answer! I just read the article http://www.nytimes.com/2010/08/27/us/27bcjames.html?_r=0, and I'm curious about whether you are going to try growing some in pots.

Answer (score 3):

I really don't know, but I get the impression they might be [magnolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia) trees. The leaves in the close-ups look about the same. They're a cold-hardy evergreen, and a nice sight. I used to see them all over Kentucky when I lived there. They have nice flowers. The trees can get large.

It might be a [Little Gem magnolia](http://www.south-florida-plant-guide.com/little-gem-magnolia-tree.html).

Comment: The page suggests these are fragrant, but is this true only when flowering? Their scent was more neutral when I visited (but the trees were not flowering).

Comment: Shule- At first, I thought you might be right, but when I went to google street view, and enlarged it, I saw that the seed pods don't look like a Magnolia. They are very different. quiet- please see the link https://www.instantstreetview.com/@37.787596,-122.402262,52.99h,4.64p,2z

Comment: Here are magnolia seed pods. http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/magnolia-seeds-400x266.jpg

Comment: @quiet Magnolia trees are not fragrant when they're not in bloom. Honestly, I didn't even smell them when they were in bloom, in Kentucky, but I didn't sniff them close up. So, they're not as fragrant from a distance, as say, a lilac bush.

Comment: @Diane How can you tell what the seed pods even look like in the first picture? :) We need a close-up.

Comment: @Diane The fruit looks different before the seeds spread out. I'm not sure if it matches what you're seeing, though, since even zoomed in, I don't see the pods. See this link: https://www.google.com/search?q=magnolia+tree+fruit&num=100&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG0eGp0v3MAhUE4WMKHVNSBuQQ7AkIKQ&biw=1920&bih=969 I never saw any seed pods or fruit on the trees when I was in Kentucky, though (just flowers).

Comment: @Shule- I agree that we need a close-up. I was not disputing your answer. But, since you said that you "really don't know", I posted an alternate possibility. I was curious, and carefully looked at Magnolia pictures, and the leaves and seed pods/fruits look different to me. Did you look at enlarged link that I posted in the comment to you up above? I will vote for your answer now, because your guess is as good as mine. http://www.whatgrowsthere.com/grow/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Magnolia-LittleGem.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40443/discussion-between-diane-and-shule).

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know, either. But, this type of leaf and fruit was identified as Camellia Azalea in an older garden stack member post. I found it while I was searching "camellias" on google because the "fruits" or "nuts" look like the ones on my own camellia japonica (but the leaves are different than Camellia Azalea). I will post the other member's pictures, and look for separate confirmation.

I see from further research that is also called "Camellia Changii", and one site said that it was pretty rare and new in the USA. This may possibly be grafted onto different root stock (although apparently that is still challenging experts.)

It seems likely that the ritzy Palace Hotel could afford such a gem. 
I look forward to confirmation from them about whether it is a camellia azalea, a magnolia, or neither one. (I also see that there are many members of the "theaceae" family that look similar, but I do not see such a close match to leaf type.)

Here is the link to the enlarged google street view that I posted above. You can see the fruits. https://www.instantstreetview.com/@37.787596,-122.402262,52.99h,4.64p,2z

From a post 3 years ago-

[What are these sphere-like things on my Camellia azalea tree?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/6003/what-are-these-sphere-like-things-on-my-camellia-azalea-tree)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlc7N.jpg

More pics here- It has the same leaves.

http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/157556/#b

Camellia Changii- https://www.flickr.com/photos/kamelienfreunde/20391131664 Camellia changii  (syn. Camellia azalea)
Picture
Camellia changii
everblooming camellia

This remarkable species was discovered in 1984 and was introduced into the United States recently. It is now in a few public gardens and in the hands of commercial growers and breeders but, in 2015, is not yet available in nurseries or catalogs. The bright red flowers may be produced throughout the year, including summer months. It is reported to grow to about eight feet tall. Reportedly, flower size varies. The largest flowers are four to five inches across. With its summer flowering season, this plant could be a very important addition to the world of camellia gardeners. However, it is reported to be challenging to propagate and camellia hybridizers are having difficulty crossing this species with others in the genus.

Comment: http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/157556/#b

Comment: Thank you for your help Diane! The hotel responded with the name of a different tree (I added as a separate answer), but I sincerely can't the difference between yours and the "official" answer.

Comment: @quiet- No, problem! :) I learned some interesting new things while I was searching. So glad the hotel got back to you! New Zealand Christmas Tree looks beautiful.